# Windows with linux subsystem; linux paths

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
C:\Users\blah>which pwd
/usr/bin/pwd

C:\Users\blah>/usr/bin/pwd
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\blah>\usr\bin\pwd
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have linux subsystems installed on windows 10, and have ubuntu installed within that subsystem.  When I run ubuntu and bash, all is right in the world.

I did notice that when using `cmd` (windows command prompt), I can use various linux utilities.  However, the paths returned by utilities like `pwd` return linux paths that are not valid in Windows.

Is there a way to run a utility like `pwd` from `cmd` by specifying a **full path** like I have listed above?

---

Windows 10 Home, version 1903 build 18362.418

I don't have Cygwin or any other gnu/linux additions on this system. It's a new computer with minimal 3rd party additions installed.

Comment: Since details are important, please specify, what version of Windows you are using.  If you are using 1909 then specify if you are using WSL 2.

Comment: What do you get from `where which` in Cmd? (I suspect you're not running WSL tools but rather Cygwin tools or MSYS tools...)

Comment: Try using `\ `instead of `/`...

Comment: thanks @grawity I think your question solves it: `C:\Users\blah>where which`
`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\which.exe` it is finding these utils in git, not from my bash installation that I thought